# Complex routes in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes

My current project should be usable all over the world. The contents I display depend on the language of the user and on the country of the user.

Example:

- domain.com/**de-ch**/site.html for german speaking people in switzerland
- domain.com/**de-de**/site.html for german speaking people in germany
- domain.com/**en-de**/site.html for english speaking people in germany
- domain.com/**de**/site.html for german speaking people, independent of the country
- domain.com/ general home page in english

Dependending on the language and the country, I display other contents or the same contents translated to the language.

At the moment, my route looks like this:

```
frontend:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}{country}/
    defaults: { country: -de }
    requirements: 
        _locale: en|us|de|ch
        country: -de|-ch|-at|
```

What I want to have is a set of routes (site.html is one example route) that is available for all combinations of locales and countries.

My current solution does not seem fine. For example, I have to prepend a dash to all countries. This also has to be done when I want to use the routes... Is there no more elegant way? Something like this?

```
frontend_only_locale:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    defaults: { country: de }
    requirements: 
        _locale: en|us|de|ch

frontend_both:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}-{country}/
    defaults: { country: de }
    requirements: 
        _locale: en|us|de|ch
        country: de|ch|at
```

How can I make two parameters seperated by a dash where the second parameter is optional? In this case the dash should also be ommitted...

Comment: Assuming you're using the Expression Language bundle, could you use a [ternary](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#ternary-operators)? Maybe like: `/{_locale}(country ? -{country})/` I've not used Symfony expressions, so that may not be right.